# Date Time Formatting not working properly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("DD.MMM.YYYY.HH.MM.SS")
```

Using the above formatting to get the current date and time as per the above format.  But it's resulting

```
DD.Sep.YYYY.15.09.SS
```

Comment: `"dd.MMM.yyyy.HH.MM.ss"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Pikoh, you made it :)  Please move it as answer post.  So that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: In fact is a duplicate, see @AFriend comment, so it would probably be closed soon :)

Comment: The second answer in the dupe target has a LOT of information you may find useful in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use This it will definetly work as per your expecting output

```
string h = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MMM.yyyy.HH.MM.ss");
```